# why is my String throw error?

Tags: c#, urbanairship.com

I want to target this string type "application/json" for urban airship api. Can you guys help me whats wrong with my string and structure?

```
string postData = "{"audience":"all","device_types":["android"],"notification":{"alert":"This is a broadcast."}}";
```

I did tried adding back slash "\" example below:

```
string postData = "{\"audience\":\"all\",\"device_types\":[\"android\"],\"notification\":{\"alert\":\"This is a broadcast.\"}}";
```

Below are my full code:

```
 // Create a request using a URL that can receive a post. 
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://go.urbanairship.com/api/push/");
            // Set the Method property of the request to POST.
            request.Method = "POST";

            // Create POST data and convert it to a byte array. 

            string postData = "{'audience':'all','device_types':'['android']','notification': {'alert':'This is a broadcast.'}";




            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
            // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
            request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

            //Do a http basic authentication somehow
            string username = "Zx5EPSG7Qhu-BvYtz0laTg";
            string password = "sIaj2CjASlm27pimHqOfhA";
            string usernamePassword = username + ":" + password;
            CredentialCache mycache = new CredentialCache();
            mycache.Add(new Uri("https://go.urbanairship.com/api/push/"), "Basic", new NetworkCredential(username, password));
            request.Credentials = mycache;
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(usernamePassword)));

            // Get the request stream.
            Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            // Write the data to the request stream.
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            // Close the Stream object.
            dataStream.Close();
            // Get the response.
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            // Display the status.
            Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
            // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
            dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            // Read the content.
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
            // Display the content.
            Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
            // Clean up the streams.
            reader.Close();
            dataStream.Close();
            response.Close();
```

I got below error:

```
400 Bad Request – The request body was invalid, either due to malformed JSON or a data validation error. See the response body for more detail.
```

Comment: What was in the response body?

Comment: You're manually building a JSON string. That's a bad idea. Instead, use a library.

Comment: `"audience": "all"'` <--- what is this `'` ?

Comment: try this: `string postData = "{'audience':'all','device_types':'['android']','notification': {'alert':'This is a broadcast.'}";`

Comment: sorry typo for ' ...i change to single '  still got same error

Comment: I have add my full code...kindly help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
{
     "audience" : "all",
     "device_types" : ["android"],
     "notification" : {
         "alert" : "This is a broadcast."
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have small type in the first value, an additional *`'`* sign after `"all"`:

```
{
    "audience": "all"', 
    "device_types": [
        "android"
    ],
    "notification": {
        "alert": "This is a broadcast."
    }
}
```

In future, you can use online validators for such cases, like [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/).